# Account Controller Password Encryption

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, password-encryption

I don't know what type of encryption does the WebSecurity class from ASP.NET MVC 4 uses to encrypt the passwords.Here is the controller action used for registering new accounts(it was generated automatically):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }


        return View(model);
    }
```

So can anyone tell me what type of encryption does it use when it saves the password in the database?